# Why do I get the error message as integral does not converge?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Can anyone please help me to find the integral value of the following expression,

```
Integrate[(x - t)^(-1), {t, 0, x}]
```

It will be of a big help to me.

Comment: This is rather a math question (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral). Mathematica 12.0 correctly returns the error message " Integrate::idiv: Integral of 1/(-t+x) does not converge on {0,x}." and the input. Other users, not only you,  obtain the same result.

Comment: The integral is a divergent, [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).  They are covered in first-year calculus, usually in the second half in US colleges/universities.